# Angular 4 : Cart array overwrite when new item pushed in the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, shopping-cart, cart

I am using angular 4 in the following code I want to add new product when user clicked on "Add to cart" option , But when user click on the next product it overwrites the first product instead of appending cart array

[Still over write the array , Please see the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZAbtZ.png)

**cart.service.ts**

```
export class Cart {
  products : Product[] = []
}

@Injectable()
export class CartService {
  constructor(private http: Http) {}
}
```

**Parent Component html**

```
<div class="row">
  <product-box class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" *ngFor="let product of products" [product]="product">
  </product-box>
 </div>
```

**Child Component html**

```
<div class="item-cart">
  <a class="btn btn-info" (click)="addToCart(product)" >
    Add To Cart <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </a>
</div>
```

**Parent Component**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Product, ProductService} from '../../../shared/services/product.service';
import {ProductBoxComponent} from '../product-box/product-box.component';
import { ProductPhoto, ProductPhotoService } from '../../../shared/services/product-photos.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'product-list',
  templateUrl: './product-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-list.component.css']
})
export class ProductListComponent implements OnInit {
    products: any = [];

  constructor( private productService : ProductService, private productPhotoService: ProductPhotoService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
     this.loadPrimaryPhoto();
  }
     loadPrimaryPhoto(){
    this.productPhotoService.listPrimaryPhoto().then(response => {
     this.products = response.json();
    }, error => { });
  }


}
```

**Child Component**

```
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Product, ProductService } from '../../../shared/services/product.service';
import { ProductPhoto, ProductPhotoService } from '../../../shared/services/product-photos.service';
import { Cart, CartService } from '../../../shared/services/cart.service';
import { SettingsService } from '../../../shared/services/settings.service';



@Component({
  selector: 'product-box',
  templateUrl: './product-box.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-box.component.css'],
})
export class ProductBoxComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() product: ProductPhoto;
  imagePath: any;
  // cart = [];
  private cart: Cart[]=[] ;
  constructor(private settings: SettingsService ) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  addToCart(products) {
    this.cart.push(products);
    console.log('cart=', this.cart);
  }
}
```

Comment: Where is this @Input coming from? Is this a child component? How does the parent look like?

Comment: Yes this is child component 
Please check my updated answer for parent component

Answer (score 1):

`ProductBoxComponent.cart` can't be an array, it is an object of `Cart` type which should initialized via `new` operator. Also, if the argument of `ProductBoxComponent.addToCart()` method has `Product` type, then it should be pushed to `Cart.products` array.

```
private cart: Cart;

constructor(private settings: SettingsService ) {
  this.cart = new Cart();
}

addToCart(product: Product) {
  this.cart.products.push(product);
  console.log('cart=', this.cart.products);
}
```

Comment: Plaese check my edited answer , it still over writes the value

Comment: @FirzaAhmed I still see the same issues: `private cart: Cart[]=[]` and `this.cart.push(products);` are totally wrong statements. And the fact you pass `products` array from `ProductListComponent` to `ProductBoxComponent` makes this special guaranteed. The type of `ProductBoxComponent.addToCart()` argument must be `Product` etc

Answer (score 0):

Try to inject your cart service in constructor like below:

```js
Component

import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Product, ProductService } from '../../../shared/services/product.service';
import { ProductPhoto, ProductPhotoService } from '../../../shared/services/product-photos.service';
import { Cart, CartService } from '../../../shared/services/cart.service';
import { SettingsService } from '../../../shared/services/settings.service';



@Component({
  selector: 'product-box',
  templateUrl: './product-box.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-box.component.css'],
})
export class ProductBoxComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() product: ProductPhoto;
  imagePath: any;
  constructor(private settings: SettingsService, private cart: Cart ) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  addToCart(products) {
     this.cart.products.push(products)

    console.log('cart=', this.cart);
  }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this behavior is, that you are creating separate instances of your child in each iteration. So each child will have it's separate `cart` with the nested array. So you are not dealing with a single variable cart for all products. So what your code does now, is to create a new cart for each instance of child component. So your products are not overwritten, they are just different variables.

If you want to use the one and only instance of child component, you should pass the array as `@Input` and iterate the array in the child:

```
<product-box [products]="products"></product-box>
```

Then iterate the products in your child, and then add chosen products to your cart:

```
<div *ngFor="let product of products">
  <p (click)="addToCart(product)">{{product.name}}</p>
</div>
```

TS:

```
private cart: Cart = new Cart();

addToCart(product) {
  this.cart.products.push(product);
  console.log('cart=', this.cart);
}
```

This way you will have just one cart, not a cart for each child component.

Comment: Still same issue

Comment: @FirzaAhmed Please compare your code to this stackblitz, the code I provided should work just fine :) https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-swcgd3?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: @FirzaAhmed Did you figure it out? :)